# Getting PayPal Live App ID

Tags: paypal

I'm unable to get a live app ID for my PayPal application.

If I go to Dashboard -> My Apps & Credentials -> My App, there is nothing there about App IDs or if it's pending or anything like that?

My PayPal account is a verified business account. The API I am using is for Adaptive Payments.

I have viewed a few other questions on SO, although all seem to have some kind of message such as `pending` within their app.

[image]

How can I obtain my live app ID?